# How to correctly expose images uploaded by web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC web application I have a web form to upload images.
These images are stored in a server folder outside web application (say `C:\\images`).

Now I need to load these images in another page, but I don't want to expose the folder as public. I think I need to map the path via a servlet or something similar...

Can you help me? Is there some easy way using Spring framework?

Comment: Why don't you handle them directly with apache http?

Comment: @ianaz never used it, can you explain?

Comment: You could also setup a servlet that takes an id from the request and then returns the image itself. Thus, your second app can perform an httprequest to the app1 and retrieve the image

Answer (score 1):

If all those resources should be served directly (i.e. you don't need Controller specific code), then you could use [ResourceHandlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources). Here is an example with a javaconfig:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:///c:/images/");
```